# jQuery Ajax request failed for get request to other domain

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to send a request to other domain like
`http://ccv.viatelecom.com/services/?item=viacall&aid=XXXX&gid=XXXX&sid=XXXX&&num=XXXXXX`

I have used Ajax request as below:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:'http://ccv.viatelecom.com/services/?item=viacall&aid=XXXX&gid=XXXX&sid=XXXX&&num=XXXXXX',
                success:function(data){
                alert(data);

                },
                error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);
                    }

            });
```

but it does not go to success function and the alert erro is:

```
XMLHttpRequest=
textStatus=error
errorThrown=
```

if I write same url address bar it display message not in Ajax request.

Is this the correct way to send request or is there another way or something I am missing?

Comment: You can't send cross-domain ajax requests to domains that dont support CORS or JSONP.

Comment: The time has come for you to undergo the first right of passage: Learning About the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). (Once you have mastered this trial, expect the next right of passage soon, Understanding How Asynchronous Programming Works.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not perform a cross domain ajax call.

Work around for this

### **Method 1**

**JavaScript**

Create a function

```
function getMyData(data) {
    alert(data);
    //Do the magic with your data
}
```

**Server side**

On server end wrap your data inside function syntax

```
getMyData("Enter your data here");
```

**JavaScript**

Then create a script tag and add a link to your cross-domain page

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
         src="cross ref url">
 </script>
```

For reference: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

### **Method 2**

Another option is Create a proxy on your domain. ie create a page in your domain which internally calls the cross-domain page and return the same data to your Ajax call.